# MS CRM Block all entity forms from user

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am an admin for MS CRM 2011 and I have this demand that certain users - although they have READ access to an entity  - should NOT have access to any of this entity's forms.
Meaning, they should only view the records via sub grids, on related records.

Is there a way to have such control over user view?

Answer (score 0):

You could make all the tabs on the form invisible unless the user had certain roles(s) through JavaScript.

This seems like a very strange request. Any chance you could elaborate?

Comment: Sam, to be more specific: Actually I need this solution for an entity which is only an intermediate (sort of an N:N) for three different entities, and since records in it are only created and edited by plugins - therefore there is no need for users to make any use of forms on it, and all it's purpose is to create linkage and produce views in grids.

Answer (score 0):

Put these users in a role. Create a new form for each entity and assign that form to that role. Make sure these users do not have access to the other forms by role. Don't put any fields on this new form and maybe even add a javascript pop-up error message and some code that closes the form immediately.

This way your other forms aren't slowed down by a javascript request that always checks role membership plus everything is contained in that special form instead of spread through your other "real" forms.

Answer (score 0):

if this entity just hold relationships like a N:N entity would do, you can also make sure that the relationship (reference to it) is not shown on the navigation area of the related entity forms.  This way its there but no one can 'use' it.